# Добавить несколько ЧПУ ссылок, которые будут вести на страницу и передавать разные параметры

Tags: mod_rewrite, wordpress

Ребят подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать следующее.

Есть некоторая страница в вордпрессе. Допустим с `id "500"` и URL "`search-results`". Для этой страницы задан шаблон, в котором есть функционал поиска по каталогу. Нужно сделать следующее. Нужно добавить несколько ЧПУ ссылок которые будут вести на эту страницу, и передавать разные параметры, например:

```
/catalog/full/
/catalog/discount/
/catalog/manufacturer/100/
```

При этом "`search-results`" тоже нужно оставить.

Нутром чую что есть простое решение. Пока эксперементирую с фильтром "`rewrite_rules_array`", но получается ерунда.

Тут может показаться что это простая задача. На самом деле не так. Т.е. добавить в `.htaccess` таких редиректов:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/discount/$ /index.php?page_id=500&CatalogType=discount [L,QSA]
```

недостаточно. Wordpress пишет, что мол `Not Found`. В общем об этих редиректах нужно еще как то `Wordpress-у` "сказать". Вот, собственно, вопрос в том - как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вобщем решил проблему.

Подключил вот такой вот самописный плагин: http://pastebin.com/vuzv6MP9

Удалите оттуда вот эту строку перед использованием (нужна для дебага, зря сильно нагружает вордпресс):

```
add_action( 'init', 'dcur_rewriteFlush' );
```

А также в htaccess прописал следующее:

```
RewriteRule ^(en/)?catalog/full/$ /index.php?page_id=500&CatalogType=full [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(en/)?catalog/discount/$ /index.php?page_id=500&CatalogType=discount [L,QSA]
```

В принципе это же можно было бы решить без правок htaccess с помощью только лишь плагина. Но там возникала проблема что необходимо было прописывать каждый _GET параметр, который может принимать Wordpress, с помощью вот такого вот фильтра:

```
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');
```

Внутри которого прописываются все _GET переменные. Но я пришел к мнению что это излишний геморой, и поэтому становился на текущем варианте.